# Get phone number telegram bot

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

Is there is another way to get users phone number in telegram bot(without button click forexample)? Now I've got this realization.

```
$btn[] = [[
                    'text'=>"SHOW PHONE",
                    'request_contact'=>true
                ]];
                $reply_markup = \Telegram::replyKeyboardMarkup([
                    'keyboard' => $btn,
                    'resize_keyboard' => true,
                    'one_time_keyboard' => false,
                ]);
                $send_message = new MessageController();
                $send_message->sendMessage($chatid, $first_name, $bot_name,$reply_markup);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

unfortunately there isn't another way. recently telegram represent telegram login. even with telegram login bot can not access the user number.